# Bold button click its found and other button click not this button in ckeditor

Tags: jquery, html

if bold button click its found and other button click not this button
e is not defined error message is shown
 please suggest any solution...

Source Code

```
$(".cke_button").click(e)
{   
  var str = $(this).attr(".cke_button__bold");
  var curr= "bold";
    if(str.indexOf(curr) != -1)
    {
    alert(curr + "found");
    }
}
```

e is not defined error message is shown

Comment: Can you explain in detail with your HTML code? What you want? Do not clear what actually you want?

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand what do you want to ask.. but as i am assuming you want to check if your button has bold class or not.. if i'm correct then
try this

```
$(".cke_button").click(function(e){
    var str = $(this).attr("class");
    var curr= "bold";
    if(str.indexOf(curr) != -1)
    {
        alert(curr + "found");
    }
})
```

or this

```
$(".cke_button").click(function(e){

    if( $( this ).hasClass( 'cke_button__bold' ) )
    {
        alert("Bold Class found.");
    }

})
```

Comment: don't forget check mark in ans if ans is useful for you

Comment: If you do not understanding question then first understand question from OP and then give answer.

Comment: this is clear in posted code he want to check weather button has bold class or not..

Comment: Then why are you writing in your answer like `i don't understand what do you want to ask..`?

Comment: @SyedArifIqbal `e is not defined error message is shown` in question suggests there is something else going wrong

Comment: because he didn't pass function in click method.